# Nginx reverse proxy to Dockerized Wordpress with Apache results in "Bad Request"

Tags: docker, apache, nginx

I have set up an Nginx server to act as a reverse proxy for a Dockerized WordPress instance that runs Apache. My Nginx configuration for SSL looks like this:

```
server {
    server_name  blog.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8020;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    server_name  blog.example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    if ($host = blog.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    return 404;
}
```

When I try to access blog.example.com, I get the following error:

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

This seems to be an error from the Apache server inside the Docker container. I've ensured that the proxy headers are being set correctly in Nginx, and I've also checked the .htaccess and Apache configurations inside the Docker container, but I can't seem to find the root cause.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any insights on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: I would try to determine how exactly the request to Apache looks and replicating it with `curl` or a similar tool. That way you get Nginx out of the equation and can hopefully easier see what's wrong.

Comment: How can i determine how the request looks? I checked the access_logs but this doesnt helps a lot

Comment: Also check the apache access.log in the docker container, but this is completely empty

Comment: now it worked, had to update the url in the wordpress settings omg...